# Stop a string split when it encounters a space

Tags: python

I have a simple string I'm trying to split `this/thing hello` and I'm doing the following:

`split = myString.split('/')`

It works, but it also picks up `hello` on the split, so the two strings I'm getting are `this` and `thing hello`. How can I stop this, and instead make it stop string splitting when it encounters the space?

I want the output to be `this` and `thing`.

Comment: What should the output be? Just `['this','thing']`?

Comment: Why don't you split by space first?

Comment: Are you after `myString.partition(' ')[0].split('/')`?

Comment: @dashiell Correct, sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: .Is this a URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString.split(' ')[0].split('/')
```

will return you the split of everything that appears before the first space

Comment: Either limit the split `.split(' ', 1)` or use `str.partition(' ')` (an optimised version for a single split) to avoid creating unnecessary list elements...

Comment: @EugeneSh. nope... using `s = 'one two three four'` as the input string... `s.split(' ', 1)[0]` is 11.1ns per loop, and `s.partition(' ')[0]` is 3.18ns per loop.

Answer (score 2):

Split it on spaces first and then split the first element:

```
split = myString.split(' ')[0].split('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop split at first space then first split at space

```
string = "this/thing hello"
final = string.split(' ', 1)[0].split('/')
```